# How to match an optional group inbetween repetitions?

Tags: regex

I need to match HTML elements and optionally their 'parent-name' attribute.

```
<rect x='300' y='1150' rx='10' ry='10' width='361' height='65' state-name='ReadyForProduction' parent-name='Active' fill='url(#grad_#9FA0DD)' style='stroke: black; stroke-width:1; opacity:1.0'/>
<rect x='300' y='1150' rx='10' ry='10' width='361' height='65' state-name='SomethingElse' fill='url(#grad_#9FA0DD)' style='stroke: black; stroke-width:1; opacity:1.0'/>
```

This expression only matches the elements with the attribute:

```
<rect[^<]*?(?:parent-name='(.+?)')[^<]*?\/>
```

This expression with the quantifier `?` matches all elements and ignores the attribute:

```
<rect[^<]*?(?:parent-name='(.+?)')?[^<]*?\/>
```

How should I go about matching all subjects and capture the group if present, between repetitions?

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GTfoYk/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should match your needs : `<rect.*?((parent-name)='([^']*)').*?\/>|<rect.*?\/>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aMrdHs/1)

**PHP Snippet**

```
$re = '/<rect.*?((parent-name)=\'([^\']*)\').*?\/>|<rect.*?\/>/';
$str = '<rect x=\'300\' y=\'1150\' rx=\'10\' ry=\'10\' width=\'361\' height=\'65\' state-name=\'ReadyForProduction\' parent-name=\'Active\' fill=\'url(#grad_#9FA0DD)\' style=\'stroke: black; stroke-width:1; opacity:1.0\'/>

<rect x=\'300\' y=\'1150\' rx=\'10\' ry=\'10\' width=\'361\' height=\'65\' state-name=\'ReadyForProduction\' fill=\'url(#grad_#9FA0DD)\' style=\'stroke: black; stroke-width:1; opacity:1.0\'/>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

[PHP Online demo](https://repl.it/HifI/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can push the part before parent-name also into non-capturing group. In case of no parent-name, the suffix after the non-capturing group will match it.

`^<rect(?:[^>]*?parent-name='(.+?)')?[^>]*?\/>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ROkKFb/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
<rect(?:(?:\sparent-name='[^']*')|\s[A-z-]+='[^']*')*\/>
```

With Regex, it helps to be as specific as possible. So basically, match the tag, and loop though matching valid attributes, with ones you want to capture first (first match wins priority). This will also make the regex much more efficient over large documents.